# send XML from zapier to another source

Tags: xml, zapier

tried to search but without any luck.

I need to send XML file once I get lead from FB

I have URL and XML structure. But didnt find any hooks for this.

Any chance you done it well?

Thanks

Comment: Send XML file where/how? Zapier will receive your Facebook lead data, and you can send that into any supported service.

Comment: To CRM. My CRM is not yet supported by zapier. So i think i need to send it using JS - ajax. but cannot figure it out. getting an error.

Comment: If your CRM is not on Zapier yet, you can either post the data to the API endpoints (using the Zapier "webhooks" action), or you can construct your own Zapier private app so you can connect your CRM directly in the zap editor. Also - if you provide specifics on the error you are getting, someone may be able to help.